# owl carousel - not show last item when is rtl and loop is false

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have 2 problem when use owl carousel2 on mobile screen size and set `rtl: true` and `center: true`.

**Problem 1:** last slide (slide 5 on demo) not show when drag by mouse or touch.

**Problem 2:** If have one slide, then slide 1 not showing.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
    owl.owlCarousel({
        rtl: true,
        center: false,
        items: 4,
        responsiveClass: true,
        loop: false,
        nav: false,
        margin: 10,
        lazyLoad: false,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayTimeout: 10000,
        smartSpeed: 200,
        autoWidth: true,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1,
                center: true,
                autoWidth: true
            },
            768: {
                items: 2,
                center: false,
                autoWidth: true
            },
            992: {
                items: 3,
                center: false,
                autoWidth: false
            },
            1200: {
                items: 4,
                center: false,
                autoWidth: false
            }
        }
    })
})
```

I create an example with js and css file from `owlcarousel2.github.io` with new owl carousel2 updates.

**Demo problem:**
https://jsfiddle.net/j7jg7ynb/6/